# connecting a database from html by using angular

Tags: html, mysql, angularjs, jdbc

I am trying to write a sample web project that connects MySQL and executing querys such as creating a new user and deleting an existing user.
I wrote all the querys (prepared statements) in java classes.
Now I am trying to write the html file so clicking a button will call the statements that are written in the java classes. 
How can I do that, without using JSF?
I want to use Angular but I don't understand how to make that connection between the html file and the java classes. Is is possible with angular?
If not, should I just use the regular JSF to do so?

Thanks

Comment: angular runs on the client, database things run on the server. your angular code needs to talk to a page on the server, which performs the database things for you

Comment: You could use ajax in client-side-angular-code to request(get/post) your server-side-java-code.